# Memory corruption when calling std::function member

Tags: c++, c++17

This is a bit of a long winded question but I cannot figure out a simpler way of explaining what is going on.

First is this low level template class which contains the `std::function` callback (assume HeaderOne and HeaderTwo are defined as two different structs):

```
template <class Type>
class TemplateClass
{
public:
    template<class Type>
    TemplateClass(Type t): type_{t} {}

    std::function<void(char*, size_t)> on_callback;
    void CheckHeader(char*, size_t);

private:
    Type type_;
};

typedef TemplateClass<HeaderOne> HeaderOneClass;
typedef TemplateClass<HeaderTwo> HeaderTwoClass;
```

Then another class contains a map of HeaderTwoClass indexed by an int:

```
class Processor
{
public:
    Processor(){}
    void ProcessPacket(char*, size_t);
    void AddHeaderClass(int i);

private:
    std::map<int, HeaderTwoClass> hdrs_;
};
```

The implementation of `AddHeaderClass`:

```
void Processor::AddHeaderClass(int i)
{
    HeaderTwoClass new_hdr;
    auto [it, inserted] = hdrs_.insert({i, std::move(new_hdr)});
    it->second.on_callback = [this](char* d, size_t i){ this->ProcessPacket(d, i); };
}
```

There is some other socket class that calls `HeaderTwoClass::CheckHeader` and if the check passes it calls `on_callback`. The problem I get is that when `on_callback` is called, the program segfaults.

If I replace the map with just a member of type `HeaderTwoClass` the problem goes away.

I have tried to debug it by printing out the memory address of `on_callback` but have found it does the following:

- when `HeaderTwoClass` is first constructed, &on_callback = 123456
- after the `HeaderTwoClass` is moved into the map, &on_callback =
  78910
- when `on_callback` is first called, &on_packet = 123456.

It seems that the on_callback is pointing to some area of memory before the std::move even though I set the callback after?

Any ideas? I'm stumped at this point. I also tried to write a minimal compile-able example to simplify and reproduce the error but was unable.

Note this code is all single threaded as well.

Comment: As you capture `this` in `Processor` member, I suggest to delete move and copy constructor of Processor.

Comment: unless `Processor` changes the location in memory I cannot see how the presented code could segfault. Are you sure the on_callback is not nullptr?

Answer (score 1):

> - when `HeaderTwoClass` is first constructed, `&on_callback` = `123456`
> - after the `HeaderTwoClass` is moved into the map, `&on_callback` = `78910`

This isn't strange at all - you are checking the address of the `std::function` member in the type (which is basically just an offset to `this`). When you move the object into the map then end result is that it is **move constructed** - that means a new distinct object (albeit with a move it's semantically fine to *steal* or `swap` resources off the old object). So perhaps this is the root to your issue. If you need to avoid that, use some pointer type instead (e.g. `shared_ptr`) - or construct directly inside the `map` using `emplace`.